# PHP: How to join two HTML tables into one?

Tags: php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom

I have two HTML tables. Each has three rows and one column only. I'd like to join them programmatically such that I get one table with two columns and three rows.

Is there some function or hack to achieve this? How can I achieve this?

**For example** 
First Table:

```
<table id="table_one">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Second Table:

```
<table id="table_two">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I want from the above two tables:

```
<table id="table_three">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: Is your input to the join function this HTML? Or are you generating this HTML in your code? If the latter, this seems easy enough if you have two arrays. `$t1 = array('data one', ...)` and `$t2 = array('data one', ...)`.  Merge those two arrays then generate your single table.

Comment: @TPoy The HTML for both the tables is generated in one `.php` file and is passed to (actually returned by the function in which the HTML for both the tables is being generated) another `.php` file. Now in this file I need to join both those tables to get the `#table_three`

Comment: The 1st php's job is to only generate these two tables ? Are you forced to return tables from it or you can return an array of data that you can use later to generate the three tables if you wish? are the data in both tables of same length (count) ?

Comment: @Enissay I am forced to return the html for the tables in a string variable. Yes the data in both the tables are same count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a way to proceed (check in-code comments):

```
$table1 = <<<'_DATA_'
<table id="table_one">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
_DATA_;


$table2 = <<<'_DATA_'
<table id="table_two">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data one</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data two</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label>data three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
_DATA_;

// Load teh 1st table
// Create a DOM object
$html1 = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html1->load($table1);


// Load teh 2nd table
// Create a DOM object
$html2 = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html2->load($table2);

// Find all rows from both tables
$rows1 = $html1->find('tr');
$rows2 = $html2->find('tr');

// Build teh 3rd table
$table3 =   '<table id="table_three">
                <tbody>';

// Insert rows cells from both initial tables
for ($i=0; $i < count($rows1); $i++) { 
    $table3 .=  '<tr>';

        // get row's innerhtml
        $table3 .=  $rows1[$i]->innertext;
        $table3 .=  $rows2[$i]->innertext;

    $table3 .=  '</tr>';
};

// finish the table
$table3 .=      '</tbody>
            </table>';

// Clear DOM objects
$html1->clear();
unset($html1);
$html2->clear();
unset($html2);
```

It creates this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly, but I did not understand the `>>>'_DATA_'` and the `_DATA_` part. Can you tell me what it is, or point to some article etc. to read up on what it is, or tell me what to Google?

Comment: Secondly the HTML for both `#table_one` and `#table_two` are in a string variable. I can extract the HTML for each table using simple_html_dom, but your variable $table1 and $table2 is not a string. How can I convert a $string to this form? What type of variables are $table1 and $table2? Sorry I am newb.

Comment: It's just another way to input strings... You can read [`here`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) about Heredoc and Nowdoc... So, if your tables are already a sting variable, then they're $table1 and $table2

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="table_three">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#table_one tr').each(function(index){
      var row = $(this);
      var row2 = $('#table_two tr').get(index);
      $(row).append($(row2).find('td'));
      $('#table_three').append($(row));
    });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
// assume we have the tables in three strings:
// table_one in $str_1, table_two in $str_2, and table_three in $str_3.

// create $str_3 by copying $str_1 and replacing the table ID
$str_3 = $str_1;
$str_3 = str_replace('table_one', 'table_three', $str_3);

// load table_two and table_three in simple-html-dom and collect the TD elements
$tab_2 = str_get_html($str_2);
$tab_3 = str_get_html($str_3);

$tds_3 = $tab_3->find("td");
$tds_2 = $tab_2->find("td");

// go through the TDs in table_three and append the corresponding table_two TD
$acc = 0;
foreach ($tds_3 as &$td) {
    $td->outertext = $td->outertext . $tds_2[$acc]->outertext;
    $acc++;
}
// done!    
echo $tab_3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried this and it works. But I couldn't figure out why have you used `&` with `$td` in the `foreach` loop: `foreach ($tds_3 as **&$td**)`?

Comment: If you use a `foreach` loop and want to modify the values that you're working with, you need to use `&$td` to pass the value of the array item, rather than a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but:

```
   <?php

    // first and second table

    //Select data
    $reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT data1, data2 FROM '.RESEARCH.' WHERE X=X');                          
    $reponse->execute(array(X)); 
    ?>

    //Begin table
    <table id="table_one_or_two">
    <tbody>

    //Loop the rows
    while ($data = $reponse->fetch())
    { 
    <tr>
        <td>
           <label>$data['data1']</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    }

    //end of loop, end of table
    </tbody>
    </table>



    // 3TH table

    //Select data
    $reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT data1, data2 FROM '.RESEARCH.' WHERE X=X');                          
    $reponse->execute(array(X)); 
    ?>

    //Begin table
    <table id="table_three">
    <tbody>

    //Loop the rows
    while ($data = $reponse->fetch())
    { 
    <tr>
        <td>
           <label>$data['data1']</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>$data['data2']</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    }

    //end of loop, end of table
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is not about SQL tables, or any databases.